# How can I see and logout active Remote Connection (RDP) in a Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, rdp, sudo

I have tried:

```
who -H
```

But I can see only my self, even though I have connected with another account using RDP, ideally I would like to be able to see and logout a user that sees only a black screen.